# Setting rowcount and column count for grid layout dynamically

Tags: android, android-widget

I am adding `LinearLayouts` to `GridLayout` dynamically. I am looking them to be displayed as a grid view.
Is it possible to calculate how many linear layouts can be placed in one row and set column count for grid layout?
Should I use gridview to align them automatically?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to calculate the column count based on the width of the `GridLayout`, override the `onMeasure` method. It provides `widthSpec` and `heightSpec` as parameters, from which you can get the actual width and height in pixels using [MeasureSpec.getSize()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec.html). From there, calculate how many columns you'd like to show based on the width of the `GridLayout` you just found, and use `setColumnCount` to make it display that number of columns.

Comment: A little late, I know, but it's not as simple as this. You also need to recalculate or invalidate the row and column spec for each subview's layout params and call `requestLayout()` before calling `setColumnCount(int)`. Failure to do so usually results in an IllegalArgumentException.

Answer (score 0):

Override `onMeasure` of the GridLayout works. Example (in Kotlin, but should be easily translated to Java):

```
override fun onMeasure(widthSpec: Int, heightSpec: Int) {
    var childWidth = 0
    for (i in 0 until childCount) {
        val c = getChildAt(i)
        if (c.visibility == View.GONE) {
            continue
        }
        val params = c.layoutParams
        if (params.width>childWidth) childWidth = params.width
    }
    val width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec)

    columnCount=width/childWidth
    super.onMeasure(widthSpec, heightSpec)
}
```

I didn't have to `requestLayout()` despite what @drdaanger mentions in his reply.